# Is Asp.Net Ajax only used at presentation layer, or also at Business Logic layer?

Tags: ajax, design-patterns, asp.net-ajax

Is Asp.Net Ajax only used at presentation ( UI ) layer, or also at Business Logic layer?

EDIT - to be more precise, is AJAX API also used at BLL layer?

thanx

Comment: Depends on whether or not you've properly architected your layers :)  Otherwise I would say it should remain only in a "UI" layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AJAX Should Only Apply To Presentation Layer....**

You must remember that [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958040/what-is-ajax-really/958062#958062) allows the client (UI/Browser) to make calls back to the server to do something.  At which point your business layer should be invoked to get/retrieve data or do something...

So when it comes to a decision on whether or not to add AJAX functionality to a website, you will most likely do it for some UI/Presentation Layer related desired functionality.  And as soon as you do add it, your business layer will be used to serve up the information needed to the client.

The AJAX technologies itself do not necessarily apply to the business layer and I would argue that they should not.  The AJAX should simply get you to a place in your code where your front end (UI Code) can work with your business layer code.

Comment: But is AJAX API also used at BLL layer?