# I can not pass values to the uploadify scriptData

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify, scriptdata

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'swf'      : '../js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : '../js/uploadify/uploadify.php',
                'height' : '60',
                'width' : '60',
                'folder' : '../uploads/',
                'muti' : true,
                'displayData': 'speed',
                'scriptData' : {'evento' : '<?php echo $galery['event'] ?>'},
            }); 
        });
```

I try to pass a value of a variable to the file uploadify.php where there will register these data in the database, but can not in any way ... I've tried looking at some papers but the result is the same ...

Comment: If you're doing what I think you are (calling a PHP script from javascript), maybe you should look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306479/calling-php-scripts-from-javascript-without-leaving-current-page) question.

Comment: Try removing the trailing comma in "'scriptData' : {'evento' : '<?php echo $galery['event'] ?>'}," . Some browsers, *cough*IE*cough* trip over things like that.

Comment: @Jay http://trailingcomma.com/ !

Comment: I tried passing a simple string to see if the error was with php, but still it does not pass "'scriptData' : {'evento' : 'string'},". also tried to remove the comma from the right but the result was the same ... I need help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tray to create session_id() and pass to this value through by uploadify.  Then call the session id from acton page. And match them.

Comment: The corret method is formData, and not scriptData.