# Allow Bootstrap inline code block to break?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on [Blaze](http://erwaysoftware.com/blaze), an app that uses the SE API to grab recent content. It works great for finding NAAs, but there's one problem. When someone `has put a whole bunch of code or even an entire sentence in an inline code block`, this happens:

[image]

When it should look like this (non-SO site):

[image]

Essentially, the inline code blocks aren't breaking, and thus are pushing the `td` out to the right. This is the HTML that is generated:

```
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top" class="col-md-1">
        <div class="score">
            <h2 style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); pull:right">0</h2>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="">
        <div class="post col-md-9">
            <h3><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561506/how-can-i-insert-php-into-a-webpage-using-javascript/22561707#22561707">How can I insert PHP into a webpage using Javascript</a></h3>
            <hr>
            <span class="post-body" style="color:rgba(70,70,70,1)">                    
                <p><code>Is it possible to insert PHP code into a webpage using javascript after the page has loaded?</code> The simple answer is no. The page has already been rendered, the only way to change it is using javascript running within the user's browser.</p>
                ...
            </span>
            <p style="color:grey; float:right">posted by <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2155068/mjrkusanagi">MjrKusanagi</a> <span>a minute ago</span></p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is all the non-Bootstrap CSS I'm using:

```
<style>
  img 
  {
      max-width:100%;
  }
  html, body 
  {
      height: 100%;
  }
  #wrap 
  {
      min-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto -50px;
      padding: 0 0 50px;
  }
  #footer 
  {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: clear; 
      border-top:1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav 
  {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse 
  {
      text-align: center;
  }
  .flag-button:hover 
  {
      background-color:red; 
      color: white
  }
</style>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to either (a) Make the `td` stronger than the inline `code` blocks, or (b) allow the code blocks to wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap sets `code` whitespace to `no-wrap` by default. You can override this by simply overriding it with a value that allows for wrapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/nNry2/

#### CSS

```
code {
    white-space: normal;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a variation of @thgaskell's answer, taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/) (changing `pre` to `code`).

```
/* Browser specific (not valid) styles to make preformatted text wrap */        

code {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```