# How to run form action and onclick event at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, function, dom-events

In this scenario only the Javascript function works. But I want to run JavaScript `function(onclick event)` and `form action` (my PHP backend) at the same time, how to do that?

```html
<tr id="tr4" class="table-danger">
  <td>Geethan</td>
  <td>
    <form action='include/action.php?user_id=3' method='post'>
      <input id="tr4_btn" class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="Take action" onclick="takeaction(this.id,'tr4','tr4_i')" />
      <i id="tr4_i" class="fa " style="color:green;"></i>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add type="submut" try?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link) may help, you just need to make the input `type='submit' value='submit'`

Comment: What do you mean with "at the same time"? You want to tell the server via [JavaScript to execute a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958040/what-is-ajax-really/958057) while the page **doesn't reload or link to another page**? Or you want to execute the JavaScript first and after its finished make the request so PHP processes it while it loads another page?

Comment: At the same time makes no sense. I'm guessing you either want to run js first and the submission after it's done (that approach is explained in Bai's answer) or you need AJAX as !Rafal mentions. Either way, I'd suggest editing the question to reflect your actual needs (for any future readers searching for a solution to the same problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you submit the form, the website will be redirect to form action, so your action if not completed, it will be cancelled.
You can try this way (jQuery).

```
function takeaction(id,$val1,$val2){
     var $this = jQuery('#'+id);
     var $form = $this.parents('form');
     //...your javascript code at here
     // after run your code
    $form.submit();// to submit form
}
```